# Used Hyper-V to create a Ubuntu VM and VHD is showing 1/8 the capacity

Tags: server, virtualization, hyper-v

My Ubuntu VM is configured with a 1 terabyte VHD.  The physical machine uses a RAID-5 8-disk hard drive. When I log in to the Ubuntu VM, it only shows about 1/8 of the storage the VHD is configured for. I'm using Hyper-V to create the VM.  I'm thinking it has to do with RAID-5, since there are 8 disks and I am seeing 1/8 of the capacity.  Is there anyway to check to be sure it isn't just unpartioned and not available??  I've been trying to figure this out for three days!

```
eric@slash:~$ discus
Mount           Total         Used         Avail      
/              120.36 GB     949.3 MB    119.43 GB

/sys                0 KB         0 KB         0 KB

Connections         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB

+rnel/debug         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB

+l/security         0 KB         0 KB         0 KB

/dev             3.90 GB       152 KB      3.90 GB

/dev/shm         3.90 GB         0 KB      3.90 GB

/var/run         3.90 GB        44 KB      3.90 GB

/var/lock        3.90 GB         0 KB      3.90 GB

+ad/debugfs    120.36 GB     949.3 MB    119.43 GB
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about setting up Microsoft Hyper-V, not Ubuntu, and so is off topic here.  Also a quick glance at the MS page on Hyper-V indicates that the free version is limited to 1 TB.

Comment: My question is how do I display unpartioned disk space. I do not have the free version of Hyper-V, and I am fine with it being limitted to 1 TB, but I am only seeing about 1/8 of that.

Comment: @Eric with any of the disk partitioning tools, including the partitioning screen when installing Ubuntu, or the Disk Utility from the administration menu, or fdisk or parted from the command line.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but what is the command and how do I interpret the out put.  fdisk man pages haven't helped me...

Comment: @Eric the 'p' command prints the partition table.  parted is quite a bit more user friendly than fdisk.

Comment: Hmmm...so this is all I have to partition: 
 copyright information of GNU Parted 
(parted) print 
Model: ATA Virtual HD (scsi) Disk /dev/sda: 137GB Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B 
Partition Table: msdos Number Start End Size Type File system Flags 
1 1049kB 131GB 131GB primary ext4 boot 
2 131GB 137GB 5603MB extended 
5 131GB 137GB 5603MB logical linux-swap(v1) (parted)

Comment: @Eric it appears that Hyper-V is not emulating an LBA48 capable disk